# Event is not being triggered for Geolocation in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.6

I created a button that looks up the coordinates of the device. There is no errors in the code but for some reason which is eluding me, the event is not being triggered.

Here is my code:

```
protected function lblCheckIn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (Geolocation.isSupported)
            {
                lblLat.text = "Finding Location...";
                geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onUpdate);


            }
            else
            {
                lblLat.text = "Geolocation is not supported on this device.";
            }
        }
```

Later on I have the event code:

```
            protected function onUpdate(event:GeolocationEvent):void
        {
            if (event.horizontalAccuracy <= 10)
            {
                Lat = event.latitude.toString();
                Long = event.longitude.toString();
                lblLat.text = Lat;
                lblLong.text = Long;
                geo.removeEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onUpdate);
                navigator.pushView(PersonSelect);
            }
            else
            {
                lblLat.text = "Updating";
            }
        }
```

Oh, and I also did the usual imports

```
                          import flash.filesystem.File;
        import flash.sensors.Geolocation;
        import flash.events.GeolocationEvent
        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent
        import flash.utils.ByteArray;
```

Any clues as to why my event isnt calling?

Comment: What is the "geo" an instance of?  Are you sure that "geo" dispatches the Geolocation events?  Have you stepped through the first block of code?  Are you sure that the event listener is being added?

Comment: geo is an instance of geolocation. I declared it earlier in 'protected var geo:geolocation'

Comment: have you instantiated an instance of geo? `if (Geolocation.isSupported)
            {
                lblLat.text = "Finding Location...";
                geo = new Geolocation();
                geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, Update);
               
            }`

Comment: @James Post that as a real answer and I'll upvote it.  I'll bet that is the proper answer.

Comment: Sorry about this, but I actually had instantiated it outside of the function. I have moved it into the function though as James has described however I am still only getting in my output, my "Finding Location" message with no longitude and latitude. Could it be anything else that I have missed?

Comment: Reading the docs "When a new listener function is attached through addEventListener(), this event is delivered once to all the registered listeners to provide the current value of the location." 

So I would expect the handler to be hit. There is a `setRequestedUpdateInterval()` method (mesaured in milliseconds) which you could try setting to a small number to try and force the location to update? Try setting it before adding the listener? 

Just took another look - try adding another check in you `if` statement for `muted` to check that the functionality isn't disabled at device level?

Comment: Hey @James I added in further a check like you said by adding in an if (geo.muted == true) and it comes up as it is not muted. I also tried it as (geo.muted) I then tried separately and in conjunction with the previous code, the setRequestedUpdateInterval() and I set it to (10) and another time as (100) and it would not trigger at all. It is such a weird problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out the ultimate cause of this specific problem. It stems from Flash Builder not installing the complete Android SDK or the IOS SDK. Once I manually installed these by copying the SDK folders to their correct paths in Adobe Flash Builder, my GPS events were called successfully.

To sum up, if you get this trouble where the code and everything looks alright but it wont call up your events, then check to make sure that your latest SDKs for Flex are installed correctly for Android and or iOS

Answer (score 1):

Have you instantiated an instance of `geo`?

```
 if (Geolocation.isSupported) 
 { 
      lblLat.text = "Finding Location..."; 
      geo = new Geolocation(); 
      geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, Update); 
 }
```

Comment: Hey James, sorry, I should of actually included it in my original post, but I had instantiated it just outside that function. I moved it now into the function instead, but all I am getting in my output is "Finding Location" It doesnt seem to trigger the event listener for some reason. I upvoted you so long as you spotted something I forgot to mention :)