# Flash Builder SDK issues

Tags: sdk, flash-builder

So I needed to install a new SDK to use the Compass ANE that I purchased. Which I did and the issue that I had with it was that the "TabbedViewNavigatorApplication" was not a supported component. So, after some research, the problem was with the new framework file. I took the framework file from the original 4.6.0 (file location shown below):

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks

and put that in the new SDK file. This fixed this issue but now I have another issue where the old code I had working has now broken.

1. GeolocationEvent.UPDATE is no longer being called
2. Camera.setMode() causes a crash
3. UIComponent.addChild(Video) causes a crash

I am able to run the program with no errors.

[Event is not being triggered for Geolocation in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691698/event-is-not-being-triggered-for-geolocation-in-flex)

This person had a similar problem to me and he says he fixed his issue but I can't work out what he did:

> I worked out the ultimate cause of this specific problem. It stems from Flash Builder not installing the complete Android SDK or the IOS SDK. Once I manually installed these by copying the SDK folders to their correct paths in Adobe Flash Builder, my GPS events were called successfully.
>   To sum up, if you get this trouble where the code and everything looks alright but it wont call up your events, then check to make sure that your latest SDKs for Flex are installed correctly for Android and or iOS

I haven't done any work with flex SDKs and if anyone can either recommend a place to download one which supports these features or has any advice on how to fix my issue I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issue. In case anyone looks for this, my old SDK would allow me to run the app from a device without requesting for permission for geolocation event. The new SDk forces you to use the permission status event.

Makes sense to me now. Just wish I had an error pop up asking for permission rather than just doing nothing.